# Диск С забило какими-то файлами. В принципе он не должен столько весить

Tags: windows, windows-11

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image]

В программе WizzTree показывает что эта папка занимает 50гб объема

Comment: Там больше 50к файлов

Comment: Приведите пример названия одного из файлов

Comment: Я добавил еще один скрин

Comment: В основном это exe файлы с рандомными буквами в разном регистре

Comment: Зайдите в свойства диска потом очистка диска и посмотрите нет ли там пункта который занимает слишком много места

Comment: Нет там максимум 10 мб. Проблема в том, что винда устанавливает обновления, а ненужное не удаляет. Поэтому набирается гб.

Comment: WinSxS - это обновления, драйвера и т.д. Часть места можно почистить в свойствах диска выбрав кнопку "Очистка диска".

Comment: 74 тысячи файлов в System32 — это не очень нормально. Полистайте список файлов, вдруг там какой-то однотипный сторонний мусор

Comment: «exe файлы с рандомными буквами» — приведите примеры? На показанных скриншотах я вижу только `ntkrla57.exe`, который, если верить интернету, является нормальным системным файлом

Comment: Добавил еще один скрин с «exe файлы с рандомными буквами»

Comment: На первом скрине определённо вирусня

Comment: Если размер у всех одинаковый - возможно, содержимое тоже одинаковое, тогда можно посчитать хэш одного такого файла и смело удалить все остальные файлы с таким же хэшем (правда, я не знаю, можно ли это сделать встроенными средствами винды)

Comment: Попробуйте загрузить один из этих файлов на проверку на сайт virustotal. Может он что-то подскажет.

Comment: Скрин с сайта. Загрузил несколько файлов на сайт virustotal. Вирусов нет. Но это странно, что все файлы весят одинаково.

Comment: Ну переустановите винду под чистую, или можно сидеть вирусы выколупывать надесь не выкинуть что-то системное

Comment: Может какой-то самописный вирус, в базе его нет ещё. Но вообще загадочно

Comment: Ссылка для тех кому лень перепечатывать https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/6725494dce5cd19e3e690cf9066d0a4b3463d92ee2bd2430c3c56fdad34f26da

Comment: И комментарий оттуда: «A malware, which generates additional files under random names in .exe file format. Came from MSI's Center, probably got breached in that day. It would run up to two processes from created files to create even more files - in the end, fills up hard-drive and Windows\System32 folder with 1,074 kb files. The signature is valid, belongs to "micro-star international co., ltd.", which is used to bypass detections.»

Comment: Я могу их удалить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Короче говоря удалил все сомнительные файлы, а именно файлы с рандомными буквами и цифрами с одинаковым весом. Освободилось больше 40гб места. Благодарю всех кто мне помог. Спасибо, ребят.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Стирание информации без выявления причин появления избыточности, может повлечь невосстановимые потери. По хорошему, надо понять причину, чтобы снизить вероятность повторения.